# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated when trying to session.getPeerCertificateChain()

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

I am pretty new to working with http/certs/etc.  I have my own hostnameVerifier set up for an apache httpclient. *(Trying to allow FQDN to not match as long as cert FQDN is still internal to our domain - not the best I know - but better than nothing)*

It works fine for most of the servers I have tested with, but there are a couple where I get

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

when I try to

```
session.getPeerCertificateChain().
```

I am able to view the certificate just fine when I go to the same link in firefox.

Below is the full code for the method.

```
@Override
public void verify( String arg0, SSLSocket arg1 ) throws IOException
{
    String certFQDN = null;

    SSLSession session = arg1.getSession();
    javax.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs = session.getPeerCertificateChain();
    if ( certs.length > 0 )
    {
        String name = certs[ 0 ].getSubjectDN().getName();
        for ( String s : name.split( "," ) )
        {
            String part[] = s.split( "=" );
            if ( part[ 0 ].trim().equals( "CN" ) )
            {
                certFQDN = part[ 1 ].trim();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IOException( "Could not find certificate chain." );
    }


    if ( !certFQDN.substring( certFQDN.length() - 11 ).equals( ".domain.com" ) )
    {
        throw new SSLException( "Not an internal host: " + certFQDN );
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Trying to allow FQDN to not match as long as the IP's they point to match*": that's actually vulnerable to MITM attacks (by DNS).

Comment: It's a step up from the currently used code that allows any sub-domain of the main domain these servers are on.  This code is used in a very limited fashion without our own company.  If I can get all the server admins to get their certs in order I can tighten up further.  Until then - this is the best I can do.  Now that I think about it though... if someone is controlling DNS how is checking FQDN matches any better than checking if IP matches. If they control DNS can't they spoof they are any server name they want? I totally believe you know this better than me, I just like to understand. :)

Comment: Well, not really. The point of proper host name verification is to prevent MITM if there is a MITM. If you assume there isn't one, then there's no problem. If there is a MITM, he can spoof your reverse DNS requests. If you want something to prevent MITM attacks, there's no point doing it half-way.

Comment: Checking the FQDN in the cert is different: you know the host name you intend to contact in the URL. If a MITM attacker spoofs your forward DNS request, they won't lead you to a machine with a trusted cert matching the intended name. Here, with your logic, you're don't have a fixed reference to compare the content of the cert to: both certIP and connectionIP are potentially under the control of the MITM.

Comment: That makes sense.  What if I scrap the IP check thing and instead check that the domain in the cert given is a sub-domain of ours.  Isn't it feasible someone could spoof DNS but not have access to a cert for one of our sub-domains?  If so wouldn't this at least weed out those potential MITM attacks even if it's still vulnerable to internal MITM attacks?

Comment: That would be better yes.

Answer (score 0):

@Override public void verify( String arg0, SSLSocket arg1 ) throws IOException {

arg1.getSession();

javax.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs = session.getPeerCertificateChain();

].getSubjectDN().getName();

) )

);

].trim().equals( "CN" ) )

].trim();

not find certificate chain." );

certFQDN.length() - 11 ).equals( ".domain.com" ) )

internal host: " + certFQDN );

}